# How to update a many-to-many relationship with a collection of entities that are on the other side of the relationship in EF with a List<TEntity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, join

I want to update the list of authors for a particular book (many-to-many relationship) in Entity Framework.

The EF generated model looks like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

I have a book instance (poltava) that has a number of currently assigned Authors (currentAuthors).
Now I would like to assign a new List of Authors (newAuthors) to that particular book.
What follows is my representation of that in code:

```
    List<Author> currentAuthors = new List<Author>
    {
        new Author { AuthorName = "Pushkin" },
        new Author { AuthorName = "Anton Delvig"}
    }

    Book poltava = new Book 
    { 
        BookName = "Poltava",
        Authors = currentAuthors
    };

    List<Author> newAuthors = new List<Author>
    {
        new Author { AuthorName = "Aleksandra Ishimova" },
        new Author { AuthorName = "Vladimir Dal"},
        new Author { AuthorName = "Anton Delvig"}
    }

    poltava.Authors = newAuthors;
```

How can I achieve that with Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your database. Entity framework automatically created a bridge table between book and authors. You can create a class for this bridge table and this will allow u to insert or update.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework automatically creates a join table for n:m-relationships which does not appear in your DbContext unless you explicitly add it your your existing hierarchy of entities.

Based on your code sample I expanded the implementation and added said join table called 'Author_Book' which should appear as 'Authors_Books' in your database.

---

**Update 1:**

*I have also added an example (**SwitchAuthorsWithoutJoinTable()**) which doesn't use the join table as part of the entities to manipulate the n:m relationship (in this case Novel <-> Novelist). Is that what you are looking for?*

---

**Update 2:**

*Now as an example of how to add and remove single entities from collections on n:m-relationships I added the method **DeletingAndAddingSingleNovelists()** with according comments.*

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace EntityFrameworkManyToMany
{
    #region Entities

    public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public string BookName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Author_Book> Authors { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        public string AuthorName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Author_Book> Books { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author_Book
    {
        // has 1 Author
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        // has 1 Book
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public Author Author { get; set; }

        public Book Book { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion Entities

    #region Entities without 'join table'

    public class Novel
    {
        public int NovelId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Novelist> Novelists { get; set; }
    }

    public class Novelist
    {
        public int NovelistId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Novel> Novels { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion Entities without 'join table'

    #region Mock DbContext

    public class DbContext : IDisposable
    {
        // Mock DbSet<T> classes
        public List<Author> AuthorsDbSet { get; set; }

        public List<Book> BooksDbSet { get; set; }

        public List<Author_Book> Author_BooksDbSet { get; set; }

        public List<Novel> NovelsDbSet { get; set; }

        public List<Novelist> NovelistsDbSet { get; set; }

        // so we can use 'using'
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        // Mock SaveChanges Method from EF's DbContext-Class
        public void SaveChanges()
        {
        }
    }

    #endregion Mock DbContext

    #region DbOperations for initial seeding, then switching and reassiging

    public class DbOperations
    {
        // fill database with values
        public void SeedDb()
        {
            seedBookAuthors();
            seedNovelsNovelists();
        }

        private void seedBookAuthors()
        {
            var authors = new List<Author>
            {
                new Author {AuthorId = 1, AuthorName = "Marc Twain"},
                new Author {AuthorId = 2, AuthorName = "Pushkin"}
            };

            var books = new List<Book>
            {
                new Book {BookId = 1, BookName = "American Literary Regionalism"},
                new Book {BookId = 2, BookName = "American Realism"},
                new Book {BookId = 3, BookName = "The Bronze Horseman"},
                new Book {BookId = 4, BookName = "Poltava"},
            };

            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                ctx.AuthorsDbSet.AddRange(authors);
                ctx.BooksDbSet.AddRange(books);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                var pushkin = ctx.AuthorsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(a =>
                    a.AuthorName.ToLower() == "pushkin");
                var pushkinsBooks = ctx.BooksDbSet.Where(b => b.BookId > 2).ToList();

                var pushkinAuthor_Books = pushkinsBooks.Select(pb => new Author_Book
                {
                    AuthorId = pushkin.AuthorId,
                    BookId = pb.BookId
                }).ToList();

                ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.AddRange(pushkinAuthor_Books);

                var twain = ctx.AuthorsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(a =>
                    a.AuthorName.ToLower() == "Marc Twain");
                var twainsBooks = ctx.BooksDbSet.Where(b => b.BookId < 3).ToList();

                var twainAuthor_Books = twainsBooks.Select(tb =>
                    new Author_Book
                    {
                        AuthorId = twain.AuthorId,
                        BookId = tb.BookId
                    }).ToList();

                ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.AddRange(twainAuthor_Books);

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private void seedNovelsNovelists()
        {
            var novels = new List<Novel>
            {
                new Novel {Title = "Crime and Punishment", NovelId = 1}, // Fyodor Dostoyevsky
                new Novel {Title = "Notes from Underground", NovelId = 5}, // Fyodor Dostoyevsky
                new Novel {Title = "War and Peace", NovelId = 2}, // Leo Tolstoy
                new Novel {Title = "The Idiot", NovelId = 4}, // Leo Tolstoy
                new Novel {Title = "The Master and Margarita", NovelId = 3} // Mikhail Bulgakov
            };

            var writers = new List<Novelist>
            {
                new Novelist {FirstName = "Fyodor", LastName = "Dostoyevsky", NovelistId = 1},
                new Novelist {FirstName = "Leo", LastName = "Tolstoy", NovelistId = 2},
                new Novelist {FirstName = "Mikhail", LastName = "Bulgakov", NovelistId = 3},
            };

            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                ctx.NovelsDbSet.AddRange(novels);
                ctx.NovelistsDbSet.AddRange(writers);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                var dostoyevsky = ctx.NovelistsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(d => d.NovelistId == 1);
                var crime = ctx.NovelsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.NovelId == 1);
                var underground = ctx.NovelsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.NovelId == 5);
                dostoyevsky.Novels.Add(crime);
                underground.Novelists.Add(dostoyevsky);

                var tolstoy = ctx.NovelistsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(d => d.NovelistId == 2);
                var war = ctx.NovelsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.NovelId == 2);
                var idiot = ctx.NovelsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.NovelId == 4);
                tolstoy.Novels.Add(war);
                idiot.Novelists.Add(tolstoy);

                var bulgakov = ctx.NovelistsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(d => d.NovelistId == 3);
                var master = ctx.NovelsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.NovelId == 3);
                master.Novelists.Add(bulgakov);

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Example using the join table 'Authors_Tables'
        /// as part of the Entities to do operations on the n:m-relationship
        /// between Author <-> Book
        /// </summary>
        public void SwitchAuthorsWithJoinTable()
        {
            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                var twainsBooks = ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.Where(ab =>
                    ab.AuthorId == ctx.AuthorsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(a =>
                        a.AuthorName.ToLower() == "marc twain").AuthorId).ToList();
                var pushkinsBooks = ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.Where(ab =>
                    ab.AuthorId == ctx.AuthorsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(a =>
                        a.AuthorName.ToLower() == "marc pushkin").AuthorId).ToList();

                // assign all of Twain's books to Pushkin
                twainsBooks.ForEach(tb => tb.AuthorId = pushkinsBooks.FirstOrDefault().AuthorId);

                // assign all of Pushkin's books to Twain
                pushkinsBooks.ForEach(pb => pb.AuthorId = twainsBooks.FirstOrDefault().AuthorId);

                // EF tracks the changes and a call to SaveChanges
                // propagates the modifications to the database
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Example for operations on the n:m-relationship between
        /// Novelist <-> Novel without the join table 'Novelists_Novels'
        /// being part of the Entities.
        ///
        /// I.  All Books from Dostoyevsky to Tolstoy.
        /// II. Add Bulgakov as Author of 'War and Peave'
        /// </summary>
        public void SwitchAuthorsWithoutJoinTable()
        {
            // I.
            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                var dostoyevsky = ctx.NovelistsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.LastName == "Dostoyevsky");
                var tolstoy = ctx.NovelistsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.LastName == "Tolstoy");

                var booksOfDostoyevsky = dostoyevsky.Novels.ToList();

                // add all novels of Dostoyevsky to Tolstoy
                booksOfDostoyevsky.ForEach(b => tolstoy.Novels.Add(b));

                // clear all novels belonging to Dostoyevsky
                dostoyevsky.Novels.Clear();

                // save it all!
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            // II.
            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                Func<string, string, bool> compare = (target, pattern) =>
                    target.ToLower().Contains(pattern.ToLower());

                var war = ctx.NovelsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => compare(n.Title, "war"));

                var bulgakov = ctx.NovelistsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.LastName == "Bulgakov");

                war.Novelists.Add(bulgakov);

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void AssignEverythingToTwain()
        {
            Author twain;
            List<Book> nonTwainBooks;

            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                twain = ctx.AuthorsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AuthorName.ToLower() == "marc twain");

                // find all books that are not from Twain in the "Books"-Table
                nonTwainBooks = ctx.BooksDbSet.Where(b => b.Authors.Any(a =>
                    a.AuthorId != twain.AuthorId)).ToList();

                // find all Author_Book entities for authors that are not Twain
                // this search is done in the join table 'Authors_Books'
                var nonTwain_AuthorBooks = ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.Where(ab =>
                    nonTwainBooks.Any(nonTwainBook => nonTwainBook.BookId == ab.BookId)).ToList();

                // finally remove all those entries in the join table 'Authors_Books'
                nonTwain_AuthorBooks.ForEach(nonTB => ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.Remove(nonTB));

                // propagate changes to database
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                // create new 'Author_Book' entities for all books that previously where not Twains
                var reassigningBooksToTwain = nonTwainBooks.Select(b => new Author_Book
                {
                    AuthorId = twain.AuthorId,
                    BookId = b.BookId
                }).ToList();

                // add those entities to the database
                ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.AddRange(reassigningBooksToTwain);

                // propagate changes to database
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Instead of replacing entire collections of Novelists
        /// in order to remove or add a single entity to the relationship
        /// its possible to just add or delete single records
        ///
        /// I.  Remove Dostoyevsky as Novelist from 'War and Peace'
        /// II. Add Tolstoy and Bulgakov as additional Novelists to 'Crime and Punishment'
        /// </summary>
        public void DeletingAndAddingSingleNovelists()
        {
            // I.
            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                // get the novel 'War and Peace' from the database
                var war = ctx.NovelsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Title == "War and Peace");

                Novelist dostoyevsky = null;

                // havent done that so far but you should
                // always check if the query actually returned something
                if (war != null)
                {
                    // EF's LazyLoading mechanism allows you to query/traverse navigation properties
                    // on your entities which is the ICollection<Novelist> Novelists on Novels
                    // it automatically loads the associated entities which are the novelists
                    dostoyevsky = war.Novelists.FirstOrDefault(n => n.LastName == "Dostoyevsky");
                }

                if (dostoyevsky != null)
                {
                    // remove Dostoyevsky from 'War and Peace'
                    war.Novelists.Remove(dostoyevsky);
                }

                // save it all!
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            // II.
            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                var novelists = ctx.NovelistsDbSet.Where(n =>
                    n.LastName == "Tolstoy"
                    || n.LastName == "Bulgakov");

                if (novelists != null && novelists.Any())
                {
                    var crime = ctx.NovelsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Title == "Crime and Punishment");

                    if (crime != null)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("'{2]' currenty has {0} {1}.",
                            crime.Novelists.Count, crime.Novelists.Count == 1 ? "Author" : "Authors", crime.Title));

                        // assign the targeted novelists to 'Crime and Punishment'
                        novelists.ToList().ForEach(n => crime.Novelists.Add(n));

                        // save it all!
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion DbOperations for initial seeding, then switching and reassiging

    #region Execution and verifying results

    public static class Core
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbOps = new DbOperations();
            dbOps.SeedDb();
            AssertAuthorSwitch(dbOps);
            dbOps.SwitchAuthorsWithoutJoinTable();
        }

        public static bool AssertAuthorSwitch(DbOperations dbOps)
        {
            string pushkin_Poltava = "Poltava";
            string twain_AmericanRealism = "American Realism";

            Author twain;
            Author pushkin;

            Book americanRealism;
            Book poltava;

            bool hasPassedBefore = false;
            bool hasPassedAfter = false;

            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                twain = ctx.AuthorsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AuthorName == "Marc Twain");
                pushkin = ctx.AuthorsDbSet.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AuthorName == "Pushkin");

                americanRealism = twain.Books.FirstOrDefault(b =>
                    b.Book.BookName == twain_AmericanRealism).Book;
                poltava = pushkin.Books.FirstOrDefault(b =>
                    b.Book.BookName == pushkin_Poltava).Book;
            }

            //before
            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                var isPushkins = ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.Any(ab =>
                    ab.AuthorId == pushkin.AuthorId
                    && ab.BookId == poltava.BookId);

                var isTwains = ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.Any(ab =>
                    ab.AuthorId == twain.AuthorId
                    && ab.BookId == americanRealism.BookId);

                hasPassedBefore = isPushkins && isTwains;

                Debug.WriteLine("AssertAuthorSwitch {0} asserts to {1}", "before", hasPassedBefore);
            }

            dbOps.SwitchAuthorsWithJoinTable();

            //after
            using (var ctx = new DbContext())
            {
                var isPushkins = ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.Any(ab =>
                    ab.AuthorId == pushkin.AuthorId
                    && ab.BookId == americanRealism.BookId);

                var isTwains = ctx.Author_BooksDbSet.Any(ab =>
                    ab.AuthorId == twain.AuthorId
                    && ab.BookId == poltava.BookId);

                hasPassedAfter = isPushkins && isTwains;

                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("AssertAuthorSwitch {0} asserts to {1}", "after", hasPassedAfter));
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("AssertAuthorSwitch asserts to {0}", hasPassedBefore && hasPassedAfter));
            return hasPassedBefore && hasPassedAfter;
        }

        public static bool AssertAssigningToTwain(DbOperations dbOps)
        {
            // you get the idea
            return true;
        }
    }

    #endregion Execution and verifying results
}
```

I hope this helps to clarify things further. I must admit I was somewhat verbose but thats due to my alarmingly high levels of boredom at the moment. ;)

If you are still uncertain please provide a more detailed problem description and I'd be happy to get back to you.

Comment: Thankyou for a very thoughtful answer. I want to update a new list of authors for one book, and I find out a simple way is: clear old authors from the book and add every authors in new list to the book :)

Comment: Ah of course this can be all done without actually implementing the join table in your model/database/code first. I'll edit my answer accordingly. But by the sound of it you already figured it out?

Comment: Yes, may call so. But I think clear and re-add all is not a very good way, especially when, list old have many author will be still in list new, it's better of we know what will be remove, what will be keep, what will be add

Comment: Okay I added a second example which is not using the 'join table'. To answer your question in the previous comment: Its of course possible to only remove specific entities from a collection in a n:m-relationship which equals deleting the associated record in the join table from the database. I'll add that as another example. Should have everything covered then. ;)

Comment: There you go. Check out Update 2 for details on how to add/remove single instances of entities on collections in m:n based relationships.